# sandboxed snap apps won't connect to network

Tags: networking, 20.04, snap

I have a handfull of snap apps.  They include Discord, Slack, Spotify, Messenger, Mailspring, VLC, and others.  Slack is a classic (unsandboxed) app.  The rest are normal snaps.

**None of the sandboxed apps are able to establish a network connection.**

I've tried...

- `snap disconnect` followed by `snap connect`.
- a system restart.
- a reinstall of some of the snaps

They all broke simultaneously a few days ago.  I'm on 20.04.  I really don't know how to go about debugging this.

Edit: To clarify, I am confident that this issue is due to snap sandboxing because whatever caused it to break affects all sandboxed snaps, and they all broke at the same time.  It happened a few days ago, but it took me a few days to notice and make the connection that being snaps was the only thing all these apps have in common.  I didn't make any system changes.  At worst, I may have installed some updates.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1281785/edit) to tell us more about "*They all broke simultaneously a few days ago*?" That seems to be critical information, every little detail helps.

Comment: Edited.  There's really nothing else I can say.  Their having all broken at once is the only evidence I have that this is snap sandbox related -- it's the only characteristic all these apps share.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I don't have a solution but I think I have additional diagnostic info. For me, if I install a snap at one location (e.g. the office) it works there but not at another (e.g. at home) and vice versa. An uninstall followed by a re-install at the non-working location reverses the situation: now that one works and the other doesn't. I suspect snap is computing which networks are allowed at install time so when you change networks things break.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I've found is to install the snap in dev mode.

```
snap install discord --devmode
```

I do not know what my issue is or why this helps.  This should not be the accepted answer.